# redirect that same page from where id is coming

Tags: php, html, session

i am trying that if user click on add to cart button from shop-male.php it goes to add_cart.php, after process complete it redirect again shop-male.php but what if user click from shop-single.php and i want redirect after process on shop-single.php
 our better understand my code is here

shop-male.php

```
<a href="add_cart?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Cart</a>
```

add_cart.php

```
<?php
session_start();

//check if product is already in the cart
if(!in_array($_GET['id'], $_SESSION['cart'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['id']);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Product added to cart';
}
else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Product already in cart';
}

header('location: shop-male');
```

?>

and another page is shop-single.php

```
<a href="add_cart?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-bag"></i> Add to Cart</button> </a>
```

i want to do from where user click add to cart redirect on that same page after process

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in your header function. Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Provide an example, this will help other users with similar but not exact same problem in the future

Answer (score 0):

try

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code assign redirect page in GET value

shop-male.php

```
<a href="add_cart?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&redirect=shop" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Cart</a>
```

add_cart.php

```
<?php
session_start();

//check if product is already in the cart
if(!in_array($_GET['id'], $_SESSION['cart'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['id']);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Product added to cart';
}
else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Product already in cart';
}

if($_GET['redirect']=='single')
{
  header('location:  shop-single');
}
else
{
  header('location: shop-male');

}
?>
```

shop-single.php

```
<a href="add_cart?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&redirect=single"> <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-bag"></i> Add to Cart</button> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) {
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    }
```

Or

You have to redirect shop-male page with current product id. You can use this code:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
$project = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
header('location: $host.$project.'/shop-male?'.$_GET['id']);
```